# Reassign Task Email Notification

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

In SharePoint 2013 Designer workflow, while sending email notification for Re-assign task to a person using workflow how to show him who Reassigned the task to him.

Comment: Use the Modified By field?